# How to format the date in PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, date

I have a field in one of my tables called "publicationDate" and its data type is `date`. However, when I make a query that should show today's date, I am having a problem on how to format it. It always shows `0000-00-00`.

This is my variable:

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

This is my query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO articles (summary, publicationDate) VALUES ('{$content}', '{$today}')";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d"); 
// 2011-09-24
```

Your string returns:

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
// September 24, 2011, 6:39 am
```

---

**Edit:**

To save date and time you can use datetime or timestamp:

```
$today = time(); // timestamp
```

Change your database field to timestamp.

or

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // datetime
```

Change your database field to datetime.

To select your data from database you can to this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM table");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// field is timestamp
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $row['date']);
// or
// field is datetime
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row['date']));
```

More informations here: http://at.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Hi, I tried $today = date("Y-m-d"); and it works. However, what if I want the printed format to be September 24, 2011, 6:39 am and not 2011-09-24? What do I have to do?

Comment: Do you want to write the string "September 24, 2011, 6:39 am" in your database?

Comment: Yes but the current datatype is 'data'. Do I need to change it to 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?

Comment: It's not a good idea to save date & time in your style in the DB. Look at my solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
```

That is the correct format for inserting into MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

If the `publicationDate` column is of type `DATE` (which it should really be) you need to format the date in [one of the formats MySql recognizes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), not a human-readable string.

Of those, most common are `date("Ymd")` or `date("Y-m-d")` if you like hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
```

MySQL date only stores the date not the time like YYYY-MM-DD

If you want to store the time as well you can use a DATETIME field which is this: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS or you could store the timestamp as a string.

Comment: Why store as a string instead of `date`?

Comment: In case you need the time as well.

Comment: In that case you should use `datetime`... it's almost always a bad idea to store times as a string when there's a native type for dates/times available.

Answer (score 1):

The value should be a string, formatted to MySQL's format: Y-m-d.